# Modifying an array outside a brace-initialized object

Tags: javascript

Behavioral question :

Why Ninja.getArrayFromInside() return an empty array ? (after Ninja.array modification)

```js
let Ninja = (function() {

  let array = [];

  function getArrayFromInside() {
    return array;
  }

  return {
    array, getArrayFromInside
  };

})();

Ninja.array = [1, 2];

console.log(Ninja.getArrayFromInside());
```

I think, it's about passing by Value or by Reference ...
(Why array is passed by value, and not by reference ?)

Same question here :

```js
let Ninja = (function() {

  let myObject = {};
  myObject.array = [];

  function getArrayFromInside() {
    return myObject.array;
  }

  return {
    array: myObject.array,
    getArrayFromInside
  };

})();

Ninja.array = [1, 2];

console.log(Ninja.getArrayFromInside());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, there are two variables called `array`: the one declared `let array = [];` in the inner scope captured by the `getArrayFromInside` function, and the property `Ninja.array`. **These are two different variables.** The first you refer to by `array`; the second you could refer to by `this.array` inside the `getArrayFromInside` function.

You initialize them both to a reference to the same array object (which is initially empty). Then, you assign `Ninja.array` to reference a different object: the array `[1, 2]`. This does not modify the `let array ...` variable; since the function gets the value of the `let array`, it returns the original, still empty, array object.

Try changing `Ninja.array = [1, 2];` to `Ninja.array.push(1);Ninja.array.push(2);`. You'll see that modifying the original array like this will result in the changes being reflected in the `Ninja.getArrayFromInside()` call.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, `array` isn't a class member of `Ninja`. `this.array` would return `undefined`.

Same for the second example.

Comment: `Ninja` isn't really a class, it's just a brace-initialized object. And `this.array` would indeed be `[1, 2]` inside the `Ninja.getArrayFromInside()` function call, because `Ninja` has an `array` property